# C++ Windows version issue with Windows 10 home

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, windowsversion

I am trying to write a C++ program that identifies current Windows version.
I saw dozens of such questions and answers but none of them worked for me.

I am running Windows 10 Home edition.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

First options that I have tried:

```
    OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
    GetVersionEx(&osvi);
    cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << endl;
    cout << osvi.dwMinorVersion << endl;
```

This prints 6 and 2 which according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx) corresponds to Windows 8.

Second options that I have tried:

```
#include <VersionHelpers.h>

if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
    printf("VistaOrGreater\n");
if (IsWindows7OrGreater())
    printf("Windows7OrGreater\n");
if (IsWindows8OrGreater())
    printf("Windows8OrGreater\n");
if (IsWindows8Point1OrGreater())
    printf("Windows8Point1OrGreater\n");
if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
    printf("Windows10OrGreater\n");
```

In this way, **IsWindows10OrGreater()** is not defined in my system and gives compile error.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, the GetVersion and GetVersionEx functions have been deprecated. Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2)

see [Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info.

Comment: So for Windows 10 only way to do is through this manifests?

Comment: @mbaros apparently not. the linked question has a very clever solution you could try.

Comment: Yes. I already saw that. thank you